# pytest detect if marker is excluded

Tags: python, pytest

I have parametrized tests which get their input from fixtures as sketched in the following snippet. These fixtures are only expected to work under certain conditions which are linked to whether or not a certain pytest marker is set.

My question: How can I ask inside the definition of PytestConfig for whether or not a certain marker is present in order to skip certain parts inside PytestConfig which I know will fail if a certain marker is excluded?

I would like to make the following snippet work for `pytest -m 'not markertobeskipped'`

```
import os

import pytest


class PytestConfig:
    # here I'd like to throw in some conditional logic along the lines of:
    # "if pytest is called with 'not markertobeskipped': ...
    missing_config = os.getenv('SOME_CONFIGURATION_NOT_PRESENT_IF_MARKERTOBESKIPPED', None)
    # here, in reality some longish loading process would happen
    assert missing_config

    @staticmethod
    def get_input_data():
        return []


class TestClass:
    @pytest.mark.markertobeskipped
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('input', PytestConfig.get_input_data())
    def test_should_be_skipped_without_error(self, input):
        assert input
```

Comment: Just move the functionality inside the `get_input_data` function; when skipped, marked tests won't run and the function will not be executed. However, right now the `PytestConfig` class looks like it should be a session-scoped fixture anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments @hoefling . they were very helpful. I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: I tried it but get_input_data still seems to be called even when the tests in which this fixture is used are skipped. hence, moving everything inside get_input_data does not solve the issue for me @hoefling